# What is wrong with my user-defined ordering function?

Tags: sorting

I've defined ordering function:

```
myOrderingFunction[arg1_, arg2_]
```

which always return `True` or `False`.

Now I want to sort my list using this function, but unexpectedly:

```
In[28]:= OrderedQ[Sort[myList, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]

Out[28]= False
```

How is this even possible? When I apply `Sort` second time, `myList` become sorted properly. Of course, the issue may be hidden in my ordering function (how?), but first of all I want to exclude all kind of problems with `Sort`

**EDIT**
  Thanks for the replies, problem is definitely in ordering function, 
but I'am still confused. Situation is like this :

```
In[48]:= testList = {{Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}, Subscript[a, 
 3], {Subscript[b, 2], Subscript[a, 1]}};
{OrderedQ[#], OrderedQ[#, myOrderingFunction]} & /@ Subsets[unsorted, {2}]

Out[49]= {{False, False}, {True, True}, {True, True}}

In[50]:= Sort[testList]

Out[50]= {{Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}, {Subscript[b, 2], 
  Subscript[a, 1]}, Subscript[a, 3]}

In[51]:= Sort[testList, myOrderingFunction]

Out[51]= {Subscript[a, 3], {Subscript[b, 2], Subscript[a, 
  1]}, {Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}}
```

As you can see, usual `OrderedQ` and `myOrderingFunction`returns same results on every pair on the `testList`, but sorted lists are different (and both are not what I want, but that is another problem). To clarify, I just want to order some basic commutators in free group on $a_i, \ b_j$ in a natural way.

Also

```
In[55]:= OrderedQ[Sort[testList]]

Out[55]= True

In[56]:= OrderedQ[Sort[testList, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]

Out[56]= False
```

And (to reply to @JasonB answer)

```
In[57]:= OrderedQ[Sort[{{Subscript[b, 2], Subscript[a, 1]}, {Subscript[b, 1], 
    Subscript[a, 2]}}, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]

Out[57]= False

In[58]:= OrderedQ[Sort[{{Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}, {Subscript[b, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 1]}}, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]

Out[58]= False
```

Comment: I guess you need to show your function so folks can reproduce the problem.

Comment: `myOrderingFunction` is kind of complicated (and I'm ashamed of my code also). Point is that it is definitely return `True` or `False` for all pairs of elements in `myList`. Just curious, maybe `Sort` have some issues that are known

Comment: There is no room for shame on stackexchange  :-)   But seriously though, can you make this happen with a simpler sorting function?

Comment: @JasonB demonstrated a case where the ordering function may fail to ever sort the list in such a way, that it returns `True` for all pairs. `Sort` also does not check *every* element against *every other* element, it kind of assumes, that if `a>b` and `b>c` then `a>c`. If that doesn't hold for your ordering function, it may require more than a single pass to get everything ordered... or may get stuck in a situation it cannot escape, like `{c, b, a}`, but according to it c>a.

Answer (score 9):

You say

> I've defined ordering function...which always return True or False.

But I don't think that's enough for it to be an ordering function.  Consider this example, which also doesn't give the results you expect,

```
myOrderingFunction[arg1_, arg2_] := EvenQ[Round[Sin[ arg1 arg2]]];
list = RandomReal[20, 100];
OrderedQ[Sort[list, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]
(* False *)
```

It's easy to see that this isn't an ordering function, since it doesn't actually *compare* the elements,

```
myOrderingFunction @@ (Reverse@list[[3 ;; 4]])
myOrderingFunction @@ (list[[3 ;; 4]])
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

So maybe a quick change should make this work,

```
myOrderingFunction[arg1_, arg2_] := 
 Round[Sin[ arg1 ]] > Round[Sin[arg2]]
OrderedQ[Sort[list, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]
(* False *)
```

That's odd, it **does** compare now but still doesn't work.  I think this is because this simple sorting function still fails one vital test,

```
OrderedQ[{1.2, 1.2}, myOrderingFunction]
(* False *)
```

So the comparison needs to have an $\leq$ instead of $<$,

```
myOrderingFunction[arg1_, arg2_] := 
 Round[Sin[ arg1 ]] >= Round[Sin[arg2]]
OrderedQ[{1.2, 1.2}, myOrderingFunction]
OrderedQ[Sort[list, myOrderingFunction], myOrderingFunction]
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, but with too complicated an example. Simply using `myOrderingFunction[a_, b_] := a < b` shows the same thing. Properly an ordering function *must* return `True` for the equality case.

Comment: True, I was just trying to guess what OP might be up to. I was trying to look up what properties an ordering function should have, but found nothing authoritative. Besides the one you mention, I was thinking that if it returned False for `{a,b}`, then it must return true for the reverse.  Are there any more requirements?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've included example of the list in the original post. All elements there are different, moreover two different ordering function which have same values on elements of the list leads to different sortings.

Comment: @JasonB, `myOrderingFunction` returns `False` in both cases `{a,b}` and `{b,a}`, which is very strange, because it should not have any weird behavior, I will put code in original post.

Comment: @user37190 - we literally can't go any farther unless you post the code for `myOrderingFunction`

Comment: @JasonB I've defined new `myOrderingFunction` which do not have this problem (for now). Code for the original `myOrderingFunction` contains four subfunctions, it is overcomplicated. Right now I am interested in abstract situation where two functions `f` and `g` gives same results on all elements of list `l` but `Sort[l,f]` and `Sort[l,g]` gives different output